# Responsive Popup Modal Form with Zend 1.11

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

I have been tasked to make a responsive registration form with the Zend 1.11 Framework. The original developer used TINY box 2 to display a non-responsive form from a global javascript file with this:

```
path = '/registration/reg-latest?format=html';

urlpath = window.location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '') + path;
```

setTimeout(function(){ TINY.box.show({iframe:urlpath,width:false,height:false,opacity:0,boxid:'regbox',close:false}); }, 4000);

I installed jquery 2.1.1 and Boostrap 3.2.2 and got a responsive modal scaling appropriately with this code:

```
                    <script>

                        function closePreRegModal() { 
                            $('#prModal').modal('toggle');
                        };

                        $(document).ready(function(){

                            setTimeout(function(){
                            $('#prModal').modal('show');
                        },4000);

                            $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                                $(this).find('input[type=text]').filter(':visible:first').focus();
                            })
                        });

                    </script>


                    <div class="modal fade" id="prModal" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <p class="modal-title"><b><span class="preregTitle">Sample Title!</span></b></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <?php echo $this->data->formStuff; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and:

calling it from a php file:

```
    //$this->renderScript('registration/reg-latest.phtml');

    //$this->_helper->viewRenderer('/registration/reg-latest', null, true);

    //$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('/registration/reg-latest', null, true);

    //$this->render('/registration/reg-latest', null, true);
```

All of these lines produce the modal without the body form content. And most of these lines replace the html in the main vertical section of the page instead of just being a popup over the page.

I am having trouble firing off the corresponding action in the RegistrationController from the PersonsController. A list of person information fills the page, but I can't execute a popup form that triggers the RegistrationController actions to populate $viewData->form content. I can render the .phtml script but the form content is null.

I have read much of the Zend documentation. I failed to implement the same thing with LightBox and FancyBox. Does anyone have advice or experience with Responsive Modal Forms with Zend 1.11? Thanks.

Comment: What is your layout structure that you are using to render your popup ? how many layouts you have ? You can use an empty layout ( only the general head section + your view content inside the body ) .

Comment: Another developer from the zendframework slack channel mentioned that popup forms and iframes are not good practices. This website is old and outdated. The developer suggested that I add a separate div, with `display: none;` in css. Then rewrite the pop up form logic inside the target page itself. I was trying to use the setLayout function but I could not figure out how to overlay the popup form over the main page's content.